# Update stored procedure did not work in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I wrote the following code, according to this post:  [CRUD Operations using stored procedure in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

```
using (var context = new SamenEntities())
{
    try
    {
        register pazhoheshgar = new register()
        {
            id = textBox1.Text.Trim(),
            name = textBox2.Text.Trim(),
            family = textBox3.Text.Trim(),
            birth_date = dateTimePicker1.Value,
            mobile = textBox8.Text.Trim(),
            email = textBox11.Text.Trim()
        };
        pazhoheshgar.id= textBox1.Text.Trim();
        context.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("OK!!!", "Done");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR!!!", "error");
    }
}
```

I already used insert and delete stored procedure, without problem, but now the "DONE!!!" message is displayed, but the change does not occur in the database.

Comment: Firstly there is no stored procedure here, secondly your not updating anything you are adding/inserting, thirdly even for an add/insert you forgot to add it to the dbset

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the new object to the dbset. If it's called registers then the code would be as follows.

```
context.registers.Add(pazhoheshgar);
```